# explicit value of the integral.

Tags: integration

If $I= \int_1^4(1+x)^{1-m}x^{-1} \, dx$ where $0<m<1.$ Is it possible to compute the explicit value of the convergent integral $I$.

Comment: See https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Differential_binomial

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B1%7D%5E%7B4%7D%281%2Bx%29%5E%7B1-m%7Dx%5E%7B-1%7Ddx) may offer some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incomplete Beta function is
$$B(x;a,b)=\int _0^xt^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1}\,dt$$
In this case we change variable $x+1=t$ and get
$$\int_1^4 (x+1)^{1-m}x^{-1}\, dx=\int_2^5 t^{1-m}(t-1)^{-1} \, dt=\int_5^2 t^{1-m}(1-t)^{-1} \, dt=$$

$$=B_2(2-m,0)-B_5(2-m,0)$$

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* gives:

$$\frac{\, _2F_1(m,m;m+1;-1)}{m}+4^{-m} \left(\frac{\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^m \left(2\
   5^m-5\ 2^m\right)}{m-1}-\frac{\, _2F_1\left(m,m;m+1;-\frac{1}{4}\right)}{m}\right),$$

where $\mbox{}_2F_1$ is a *hypergeometric* function.